# <ui:inputText> keyup returns incorrect value (one less)

Tags: lightning, salesforce-lightning

I am using  in one of the lightning components and I am using it to filter a table. But when I'm trying to get its value in JS controller with the `keyup` function, it's giving one less value than actual.

This question has been already asked for HTML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314495/input-value-onkeydown-returns-incorrect-value-one-less) , But for HTML, we have a solution that we can use `onkeyup` instead of `keyup`. 
But in salesforce lightning, we don't have any `onkeyup` function for ui:inputText  [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm)  , 
So how to solve this issue?

I have already tried keypress, keyup, keydown.
All are giving one less value than actual one

Component :

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="search-phrase" class="slds-input"    keyup="{!c.filterTable}"  placeholder="Search Table"  />
```

JS Controller :

```
   , filterTable :function(component, event, helper) { 

        var dynamicVal = component.find("search-phrase");
        var week = dynamicVal.get("v.value") ;
        alert((week+'').toLowerCase());
             var searchTerm = (week+'').toLowerCase() ;
                $('#userTbl tbody tr').each(function(){
                    var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                        $(this).hide();
                    }else{
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it's solution. 
Just need to add `updateOn="keyup"` in `<ui:inputText>`

So new one will become :

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="search-phrase" class="slds-input" updateOn="keyup"   keyup="{!c.filterTable}"  placeholder="Search Table"  />
```

Answer (score -1):

Include **updateOn** attribute to ui:inputtext control. By default, it is mapped to **change** event so you will get only the exact value when the change event fires. updateOn="eventName"

event details : [enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm)

Comment: Your answer is not different than of Brian's finding.